# Audio file Inserted in Webpage is not taking Actions, Help me here

Tags: python, html, css, python-3.x

I'm creating a website in python that displays podcasts and images and all. I did insert audio file in HTML, it is showing but when I click on play it's not taking actions. Help me out here.

I'm supplying codes in [image]for details.

Thanks.

Comment: is the path in src correct? i see extension as pm3.

Comment: so is it working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think the extension file is different, It is **mp3** not **pm3**, You can give this format as example for .ogg .opus .mp3. There may also be problem with the double angle brackets. It should look like this ideally

```html
<source src="Lesson1.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
```